# What gstreamer packages to install for PiTiVi

Tags: video-editor

[This page](http://www.pitivi.org/manual/gstreamer.html) describes the various `gstreamer` packages used by `PiTiVi` but does not give actual package names.  Which gstreamer packages do I need to install?  What other packages may be needed?

Here is what my PiTiVi looks like... notice the disabled `Render Project` button on the top and disabled timeline editing buttons on the bottom.

[image: Here]

Comment: Did the answer & comments below help you?

Answer (score 1):

The "aptitude" function in Ubuntu terminal installs any application you tell it to w/ all the needed dependencies along with it.

If you don't already have "aptitude" installed, use "sudo apt-get install aptitude".

And than use "sudo aptitude install pitivi".

At least for me, I need "gstreamer0.10-gnonlin" along w/ PiTiVi to get it to work (might be more for you because I could already have other dependencies satisfied).

[image]

Comment: I did that... but I am still seeing a disabled "Render" button on the top and the timeline editor buttons on the bottom (I will add a screenshot into my question)

Comment: to be able to render you need to add videos/audios/images from your media library to the timeline... you can do so by dragging and dropping any vids you have in your library into the area w/ the timescale (the area above the timeline editor buttons)... from the screenshot it looks like you have an empty project on you hands, nothing to render...  when you press the green play button below the black box on the right does it play anything?  that is your edited project that you can be saved to whatever format that PiTiVi supports...

Comment: Personally I prefer OpenShot Video Editor for its simplicity and wide array of formats available during export... I like Avidemux but I've been having problems with the QT version of it not picking up my audio engine and always setting it to dummy... No problems w/ the GTK version of Avidemux so I might try that later on but for now OpenShot is powerful enough from my needs.